# Add date to logs in /var/log/cloud-init.log in ec2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I would like to add time dates to logs in /var/log/cloud-init.log that is created as an output of user-data script that is running at the beginning of the ec2 instance.

I tried to use
`echo "Start script date: $(date)"` 
and
`echo "Start script date: $(date)" > /var/log/start_script_date.log`

but in both cases I get:
`2023-08-05 07:28:32,843 - __init__.py[WARNING]: Unhandled non-multipart (text/x-not-multipart) userdata: 'b'echo "Start script date:'...'`

Comment: The default location for cloud-init user data logs is /var/log/cloud-init-output.log

Comment: You are right.  But my question is about is still about adding date